# Using Partitioning and Indexing on Same Column in Oracle is there any benefit out there

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We are having a database design where we have table on which we have 1 Day Interval Partitioning on the column named as "5mintime" and on the same column we have created index also.
"5mintime" column can have data such as 1-Mar-2011,2-Mar-2011, in short there is no time component in it and from the UI also the user can select only one day period as minimum date.
My question is that while firing the select queries is there any advantage gained because of indexes since the partition is already there, on the flip side if i remove the indexes the insertion will be come faster, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's called 5mintime but there's no time component? Seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, then I think there's no need for the index:
A local index is indexed for every partition, which in your case has the same value in all rows (ie: 1-Mar-2011 in the 1-Mar-2011 partition, 2-Mar-2011 in the 2-Mar-2011 partiotion and so on).
A global Index will actually index the whole table but will find a whole partiotion, which is also not usefull since you already have partiones ...

But, why not check it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will surely check it out, but i thought of putting this in this forum to get a quick answer,so index is not useful because oracle will never going to use it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If each day's data goes into its own partition and you can never search within days, but only for entire days worth of data, then, no, I don't see this index adding any value.

You can confirm whether or not SQL queries are using this index by enabling monitoring:

`alter index myindex monitoring usage;`

And then check to see if it's been used by querying `v$object_usage` for it some time later.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I will try this thing out , but i have one more question  i have one more field that is appid(application id) on which we create index, now the size of the data coming to the system is huge that is 350 million rows coming daily in a single partition as described based on the "5mintime" and data is for 2000 appids, so does it make a sense to create a subpartion based on appids also and then do i need the appid on index.

Comment: You need to index and partition based on how you use your data.  If you purge data by that 5mintime column, it makes sense to partition by it.  If most queries don't include appid, why partition or index on it?

Comment: All the queries are using both this criteria that is appid and 5mintime as the filtering criteria.